# How many ways to form a group of $m$ people out of a group of $n$ people

Tags: probability

> We have a larger group of 10,000 people, and we want to randomly pick 200 people from this group. In how many ways can we do it?

I stumbled across the problem above and I started thinking about it. I had no clue what to do initially so I just looked at small cases. Let $A_n$ denote the amount of people in the bigger group and $B_n$ the amount of people in the smaller group. Then reformulate the above problem with different values of $A_n$ and $B_n$:

$$A_n=3$$

We give the people names: $A = \{a,b,c\}$. Then we have:

- $B_n=1$: we can form 3 groups: $\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}$.
- $B_n=2$: we can form 3 groups: $\{ab\}, \{ac\}, \{bc\}$.
- $B_n=3$: we can form 1 group: $\{a,b,c\}$.

$$A_n = 4$$

We give the people names: $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$. Then we have:

- $B_n=1$: we can form 4 groups.
- $B_n = 2$: we can form 6 groups: $\{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,d\}, \{b,c\}, \{b,d\}, \{c,d\}$.
- $B_n = 3$: we can form 4 groups: $\{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,d\}, \{a,c,d\}, \{b,c,d\}$.
- $B_n = 4$: we can form 1 group.

$$A_n = 5$$

We give the people names: $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Then we have:

- $B_n=1:$ we can form 5 groups.
- $B_n = 2:$ we can form 10 groups: $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{a,d\}$, $\{a,e\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{b,d\}$, $\{b,e\}$, $\{c,d\}$, $\{c,e\}$, $\{d,e\}$
- $B_n = 3:$ we can form 10 groups: $\{a,b,c\}$, $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b,e\}$, $\{a,c,d\}$, $\{a,c,e\}$, $\{a,d,e\}$, $\{b,c,d\}$, $\{b,c,e\}$, $\{b,d,e\}$, $\{c,d,e\}$.
- $B_n = 4:$ we can form 5 groups:  $\{a,b,c,d\}$, $\{a,b,c,e\}$, $\{a,b,d,e\}$, $\{a,c,d,e\}$, $\{b,c,d,e\}$
- $B_n = 5:$ we can form 1 group.

So I've found a lot of surprising patterns in this (for example, add $B_n = 0$ and you get Pascal's triangle) but I still do not know how to generally do this.

All I learned is that if $A_n = x$ and $B_n = y$, then you need to look at Pascal's triangle, go to the $x+1$th row and pick the $y$th element to find the answer to the OP (I think). But now the problem is that I don't know how to calculate a specific entry in Pascal's triangle given only a row and column, and I think that problem is much harder than our initial problem.

So my question is what I'm missing here in my attempt to solve the problem (and similar types of problems).

Comment: Here is what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about simple combinations in which the order doesn't matter (namely: $AB$ as a group of two objects is identical to $BA$).

In that case you have a simple formula with is:

$$C_{n, k} = \frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}$$

Where $n$ is the total number of objects and $k$ is the elements you want to group.
In your case you have $n = 10,000$ and $k = 200$.

Remembering the definition of factorial:

$$n! = n\times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \ldots \times 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

You have:

$$C_{10,000\ , 200} =  \frac{10,000!}{200!\cdot (10,000 - 200)!} = \text{A very BIG number} \approx 1.7\cdot 10^{424}$$

If instead order does count, then you have Simple Dispositions:

$$D_{n, k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

Which in your case is

$$D_{10,000\ , 200} = \frac{10,000!}{(10,000 - 200)!} = \text{a HUGE number} \approx 1.3\cdot 10^{799}$$

**More here**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination